# Noether charge in light-cone coordinates (1+1D)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, noethers-theorem

I have read in this article http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2917 that the noether charge (in 1+1 D)
$$ Q= \int dx \; q_t$$
could be  written in terms of lightcone coordinates $x^\pm = t\pm x$ as
$$Q=\int dx^+ q_+ - \int dx^- q_-.$$
I just do not understand how to get this expression starting from the usual form of the noether charge. If someone could clarify this, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What have you done to try to figure it out yourself?

Comment: In this paper read carefully from equations A1 to A5 in particular.

Comment: Well this is the first time I am confronted to an integral where i have to split in 2 different ones, I just do not know what I am allowed to do in this case.

Comment: In fact I think I know how to get this. There is no general way to do such a split, you can do it here because q is conserved, meaning you can do a triangle closed contour!